# Contact Form Stopped working after adding implementing SSL, it's PHP based and was working fine before https was added

Tags: php, html, ssl, https, contact-form

Contact Form on my website stopped working after adding implementing SSL, it's PHP based and was working fine for 5 years before when it was just http.

Now when the form is filled correctly the message *"Sorry! Unfortunately, your message could not be sent. The form as you filled it out is displayed below. Make sure each field completed, and please also address any issues listed below:" keeps appearing.

It might be a simple issue but I don't know PHP and found this on a tutorial - would really help if anyone point out the issue and how to resolve it.

I can provide more details if needed.

Thanks!!

```
<?php

// Information to be modified

$your_email = "mail@website.com"; // email address to which the form data will be sent
$subject = "Visitor Message from  Website"; // subject of the email that is sent
$thanks_page = "thankyou.htm"; // path to the thank you page following successful form submission
$contact_page = "../contact.htm"; // path to the HTML contact page where the form appears


// Nothing needs to be modified below this line

if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header( "Location: $contact_page" );
  }

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $nam = $_POST["name"];
    $ema = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $com = $_POST["comments"];
    $spa = $_POST["spam"];

    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) { 
    $nam = stripslashes($nam);
    $ema = stripslashes($ema);
    $com = stripslashes($com);
    }

$error_msg=array(); 

if (empty($nam) || !preg_match("~^[a-z\-'\s]{1,60}$~i", $nam)) { 
$error_msg[] = "The name field must contain only letters, spaces, dashes ( - ) and single quotes ( ' )";
}

if (empty($ema) || !filter_var($ema, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $error_msg[] = "Your email must have a valid format, such as name@mailhost.com";
}

$limit = 1000;

if (empty($com) || !preg_match("/^[0-9A-Za-z\/-\s'\(\)!\?\.,]+$/", $com) || (strlen($com) > $limit)) { 
$error_msg[] = "The Comments field must contain only letters, digits, spaces and basic punctuation (&nbsp;'&nbsp;-&nbsp;,&nbsp;.&nbsp;), and has a limit of 1000 characters";
}

if (!empty($spa) && !($spa == "4" || $spa == "four")) {
    echo "You failed the spam test!";
    exit ();
}

// Assuming there's an error, refresh the page with error list and repeat the form

if ($error_msg) {
echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
<style>
    body {background: #f7f7f7; font: 100%/1.375 georgia, serif;padding: 20px 40px;}
    form div {margin-bottom: 10px;}
    .content {width: 40%; margin: 0 auto;}
    h1 {margin: 0 0 20px 0; font-size: 175%; font-family: calibri, arial, sans-serif;}
    label {margin-bottom: 2px;}
    input[type="text"], input[type="email"], textarea {font-size: 0.75em; width: 98%; font-family: arial; border: 1px solid #ebebeb; padding: 4px; display: block;}
    input[type="radio"] {margin: 0 5px 0 0;}
    textarea {overflow: auto;}
    .hide {display: none;}
    .err {color: red; font-size: 0.875em; margin: 1em 0; padding: 0 2em;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Sorry!</h1>
        <p>Unfortunately, your message could not be sent. The form as you filled it out is displayed below. Make sure each field completed, and please also address any issues listed below:</p>
        <ul class="err">';
foreach ($error_msg as $err) {
echo '<li>'.$err.'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>
    <form method="post" action="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input name="name" type="text" size="40" maxlength="60" id="name" value="'; if (isset($_POST["name"])) {echo $nam;}; echo '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
            <input name="email" type="email" size="40" maxlength="60" id="email" value="'; if (isset($_POST["email"])) {echo $ema;}; echo '">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="comm">Comments</label>
            <textarea name="comments" rows="10" cols="50" id="comm">'; if (isset($_POST["comments"])) {echo $com;}; echo '</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="hide">
            <label for="spam">What is two plus two?</label>
            <input name="spam" type="text" size="4" id="spam">
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>';
exit();
} 

$email_body = 
    "Name of sender: $nam\n\n" .
    "Email of sender: $ema\n\n" .
    "COMMENTS:\n\n" .
    "$com" ; 

// Assuming there's no error, send the email and redirect to Thank You page

if (isset($_REQUEST['comments']) && !$error_msg) {
mail ($your_email, $subject, $email_body, "From: $nam <$ema>" . "\r\n" . "Reply-To: $nam <$ema>");
header ("Location: $thanks_page");
exit();
}  
}
```

Comment: can you share with me the link to where that form uploaded?

Comment: Try `<form method="post" action="'. $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']. '">` instead of `<form method="post" action="', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '">`. (dots instead of commas for concatenation)

Comment: Replace action with  "https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']   then try again

Comment: @mbesson Thanks! Will try it and let you know.

@ Munawar Thanks. Do you mean <form method="post" action="',"https://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '"> could you pls. explain a bit more

Comment: @saicode see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php. Concatenation means "put two strings (or more) together, so it's just 1 string.
The concatenation operator in php is the dot. e.g. : `"hello" . "  " . "world"` will result into `"hello world"`. But `"hello", " ", "world"` (note commas intead of dots) is a syntax error in this case.